# Перебор переменных до существующего значения

Tags: python

Нужен способ получить значение из первой существующей переменной

Например:

```py
>>>a = 1
>>>b = 2
>>>c = 3
>>>fn(a, b, c)
1
```

или

```py
>>>b = 2
>>>c = 3
>>>fn(a, b, c)
2
```

Я понимаю, что это может быть и не функция, но делать много try except не хочется, ведь переменных может быть любое другое количество.

**UPD**

Это могут быть и элементы списка, если он недостаточно длинный

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Какой-то переменной может не существовать, например, недостаточно длинный список

Comment: на несуществующую переменную вы будете получать `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`, может вы что-то иное имеете в виду?

Comment: Я так и написал, что это не функция должна быть, а какая-то другая конструкция

Comment: Пересмотрите логику Вашего кода. Появление задачи на проверку существования переменной это очень плохой знак.

Comment: Это я очень упрощённо написал, эти переменные получены из другой среды, не из моего кода

Answer (score 0):

```
def kek(*args, **kwargs):
    [print(x) for x in args if x]
    [print(kwargs[x]) for x in kwargs]

kek(None,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, a='b')
```

Пользуйтесь `*args` и `**kwargs`

Comment: Можно в args передать не значение переменной, а ссылку на неё?

Comment: По умолчанию ссылка передается.

Comment: Если реализовывать функцией, то надо как-то не словить исключение, а если передавать несуществующую переменную или элемент списка, то будет исключение

Comment: Если вы не можете побороть исключения, то обработайте их.

Comment: То есть нет метода быстрее и эффективней, чем поочереди обрабатывать исключения при каждом присваивании?

Comment: Может и есть, но, видимо, вы нашаманили с кодом. Если отрефакторите, то скорее всего, этой проблемы не возникнет.

Comment: есть два списка a, b и переменная ExVal в каждой итерации цикла в переменную sum прибавляется a[i], но если a[i] не существует, то b[i], а если и его не существует, то добавляется ExVal. Примерно так должен код работать

Comment: И зачем тут нужна проверка на существование переменной? Условно: `if i >= len(a): ... if i >= len(b): sum += exval`.

Answer (score 0):

Если знаешь все возможные переменные, то можно так, тогда ошибок о несуществующих переменных не будет

```
b = 2
c = 3
def func(a="", b="", c=""):
    lst = [a, b , c]
    for i in lst:
        if i != "":
            return i
            exit()



print(func(b, c))

2
```

Comment: А если переменная -- элемент списка?